# jade подключение стилей

Tags: css, jade

В общем не понимаю в чём проблема, почему-то не подключается файл стилей и пишет ошибку -

> Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both

Кто что скажет?

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='../public/css/bootstrap.min.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='../public/css/home.css')
    body
        div.container
```

Comment: Используйте или пробелы, или табуляцию для отступов, но не одновременно и то, и другое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both`
*Вам перевести?*
Некорректные отступы. Можно использовать или табы или пробелы, но не оба варианта одновременно

Comment: проблему решил, спасибо)) хотя вроде бы с самого начала отступы формировал табами! аж стыдно в таких местах делать ошибки)))